# Java JComponent cannot be converted to PopupMenu

Tags: java

hi I'm learning java reading O'Reilly "Learning Java" and this code is giving me an error. is it because I've installed java 8 and the book is about java 7?

this is the first version that runs fine:

```
HelloJava.java

import java.swing.*;

public class HelloJava {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Hello, Java!" );
        JLabel label = new JLabel( "Hello, Java!", JLabel.CENTER );
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setSize( 300,300 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

this is the second version which gives error:

```
HelloJava.java

import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloJava {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Hello, Java!" );
        frame.add(new HelloComponent());
        frame.setSize( 300,300 );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


HelloComponent.java

import java.awt.*;

class HelloComponent extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
        g.drawString( "Hello, Java!", 125, 95);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace.

Comment: HelloComponent.java does not know what `JComponent` is, because you didn’t import it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine other than that you should include

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
```

to your `HelloComponent.java` class.